# Redirect to a wrong url when a model of singular resource gets updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Profile updating redirects to a wrong URL with the original user id.

The URL of profile has `users/user's_random_id/profile` and after I edit and update it on
`users/user's_random_id/profile/edit`, it redirects to `users/id/profile`.

For example, `users/abcdef/profile/edit` redirects to `users/1/profile` after updating.
"abdef" and 1 are actually the same object so it's almost correct but I want "abcdef." I want it to redirect to `users/abcdef/profile/` after updating.

The profile model belongs to the user model.

The user has `to_param` and it works well for its controllers.

The route

```
resources :users, param: :random_id do
    member do
      resource  :profile,    only: [:show, :edit, :update]
    end
end
```

Profile controller

```
  def show
    # @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @user = User.find_by(random_id: params[:random_id])
    
    @profile = @user.profile
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by(random_id: params[:random_id])
    @profile = @user.profile


    if @profile.update(profile_params)
      @profile.update(age: @profile.get_age)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to user_profile_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override ActiveRecord::Base#to_param of a related model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def to_param
    random_id
  end

  # or
  alias_method :to_param, :random_id
end
```

And change the routes `param`.

```rb
resources :users, param: :random_id
```

Or you can use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

Comment: Oh, I already put to_param in User. And it works well for Users. But somehow when I try to edit and update Profile which belongs to User, it redirects to a URL with user's id.

Comment: Ah I understand your issue. Let me think again.

Comment: Can you try friendly_id gem? In my experience, it was working well.

Comment: I have tried it before but I decided not to use it at this time.